# radio button click events

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm having an issue with my if statement registering the correct answer once I click submit. It keeps registering as incorrect no matter what I put in the if statement. Can someone help?! :)

HTML:

```
<!-- This is the HTML portion of the code related to the Trivia Game.-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Tim Decilveo's Trivia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="trivia-game-header">Tim's Triple Trivia!</h1>
        <p>The rules of the game are simple. Click the start button and begin the game! Watch the clock because the game is counting down!</p>


        <button id = "start-button">Start</button>

        <div id = "timer"></div>
        <br>
        <div id = "questionQ"></div>

<!--        <div id = "submit-button"></div> -->
        <button id = "submit-button">Submit</button>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/jquery.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
// use the 1-customer-object.html for the questions and answer section
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-button").hide();
    $("#start-button").click(function() {
        $("#start-button").hide();
        $("#submit-button").show();
        // $(this).parent().remove();

        // *** Timer that runs down to 0 ***
        var number = 5000;
        var intervalId;

        var questions = {
            questionsArray: [{
                question: "1) What is the fastest bird on foot?",
                a: "Ostrich",
                b: "Sparrow",
                c: "Eagle",
                d: "Woodpecker",
            // },
            // {
            //  question: "2) How long is one regular term for a U.S. Representative?",
            //  a: "3 years",
            //  b: "2 years",
            //  c: "4 years",
            //  d: "5 years",
            // },
            // {
            //  question: "3) Which of the following states is not on the Gulf of Mexico?",
            //  a: "Georgia",
            //  b: "Alabama",
            //  c: "Texas",
            //  d: "Mississippi",
            // },
            // {
            //  question: "4) What white, puffy clouds are known as 'fair weather' clouds?",
            //  a: "Cumulus",
            //  b: "Cumulonimbus",
            //  c: "Stratus",
            //  d: "Cirrus",
            // },
            // {
            //  question: "5) Between 1455 and 1485, the War of the Roses took place in what country?",
            //  a: "France",
            //  b: "England",
            //  c: "Germany",
            //  d: "Spain",
            // },
            // {
            //  question: "6) It's three fifteen PM. What is the degree difference between the hour hand and minute hand?",
            //  a: "0 degrees",
            //  b: "6 degrees",
            //  c: "7.5 degrees",
            //  d: "90 degrees",
            }]
        };

        function run() {
            intervalId = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
            function decrement() {
                number--;
                $("#timer").html("<div>Time Left on the Clock: " + number + "</div>");
                if (number === 0) {
                    stop();
                    alert("Time Up!");
                }
            }
            function stop() {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < questions.questionsArray.length; i++){
            $("#questionQ").append("<div>" + questions.questionsArray[i].question + "</div><br>"
            + "<div><input type = 'radio' name = " + i + " value = " + questions.questionsArray[i].a + " id = 'disable1' " + i + ">" + questions.questionsArray[i].a + "</div>"
            + "<div><input type = 'radio' name = " + i + " value = " + questions.questionsArray[i].b + " id = 'disable2' " + i + ">" + questions.questionsArray[i].b + "</div>"
            + "<div><input type = 'radio' name = " + i + " value = " + questions.questionsArray[i].c + " id = 'disable3' " + i + ">" + questions.questionsArray[i].c + "</div>"
            + "<div><input type = 'radio' name = " + i + " value = " + questions.questionsArray[i].d + " id = 'disable4' " + i + ">" + questions.questionsArray[i].d + "</div><br>");
        }

        $("#submit-button").click(function(){
            function answerKey(){
                var answers = {
                    answersArray:
                    [{answer0: "Ostrich"},
                    {answer1: "2 years"},
                    {answer2: "Georgia"},
                    {answer3: "Cumulus"},
                    {answer4: "England"},
                    {answer5: "7.5 degrees"}]
                };
                var clickA = $("#disable1").click(function(){console.log($(this).attr("checked", true).val());});
                var clickB = $("#disable2").click(function(){console.log($(this).attr("checked", true).val());});
                var clickC = $("#disable3").click(function(){console.log($(this).attr("checked", true).val());});
                var clickD = $("#disable4").click(function(){console.log($(this).attr("checked", true).val());});
                if( clickA === answers.answersArray.answer0){
                    console.log("correct");
                }
                else if ( clickA != answers.answersArray.answer0){
                    console.log("incorrect");
                }
            }
            answerKey();
        });

        // Run the functions after start button click
        run();
    })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answersArray is an array so to access the answer0 you should so following:

```
answers.anwsersArray[0].answer0
```

this way you can access the first element of the array and you will get the value

Comment: That still registers it as "incorrect" in the console.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this quickly?

Comment: your clickA is an array object let me dig into it but the second part of the statement will still be what i gave

Comment: ok so what happens is on click on #disable1 the element is assigent to clickA variable so to get the value you have to do $(clickA).value which will return the value. if( $(clickA).value == answers.answersArray.answer0){
     console.log("correct");
    }

Comment: this will fix it

Comment: and your previous statement were right so just replace back to the older version but add this  $(clickA).value

Comment: a tip always use === instead of == for type check

Comment: adding the $(clickA).val() makes every button log "correct" in the console rather than the actual index position in the array.

Comment: can you check if what the values are for each of them and use ===. Or we can collaborate on jsfiddle